# Nomencl Error - Unable to produce 2nd line of nomenclature

Tags: nomencl

```
\documentclass[9pt,conference,a4paper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}

 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{nomencl}

 \makenomenclature


 \begin{document}


\nomenclature{$k$}{set of hourly intervals}
\nomenclature{$a$}{index for power}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Why every time I run, it will only show the ***first line*** which is ***'k'***, and ***'a'*** won't show up. Another mistake is that, every time I tried to edit the nomenclature, it will just repeat the fist specified nomenclature which is ***'k'***.
For example: I change this ***\nomenclature{$k$}{set of hourly intervals}*** to the one below

```
\nomenclature{$t$}{index for time}
```

However, the output will still present k - set of hourly intervals

Comment: Try writing anything in the document and compiling it. The command does not print if there is nothing else in the document, for some reason. It worked for me.

Comment: actually, I wrote something, I just put the question that way to put focus on the problem. The problem is even worse, even if I haven't specified a nomenclature and just put \printnomenclature, it still results to the 'k'. @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: Hm... Okay. Can you show me the `.nlo` and `.ilg` files, please? Perhaps they have something useful.

Comment: This is what i used: makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: Oh, sorry, then it's `.nlo` (the input file for makeindex) and `.nlg` (the log file). You can upload them to https://pastebin.com/ or something like that.

Comment: after downloading, where would i put it? @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: Upload these two files to https://pastebin.com/ and give the link to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem by:

1) Everytime you add multiple nomenclature, check via ***TOOLS***

2) Click Index

3) Click Run, then VIOLA you have the desired output.

4) Do the same everytime you add another line, this is via texStudio

NOTE: Use this in Configuring your Index via commands

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```